# Angular serve works in dev but fails in prod due to a form related import

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-forms, ng-build

I get the following error when I run a prod build on my Angular 9 app.

[image]

ERROR in Can't export value FormControl in  from MaterialModule in  as it was neither declared nor imported!

I have imported FormsModule and ReactiveForms Module in my App Module and a shared Module called

```
// Angular Material Components
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

const MatModules = [

  ReactiveFormsModule,
  FormControl,
  FormsModule,
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ],
  imports : [
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
   ],
  exports : [ MatModules ]
})

export class MaterialModule { }
```

Kindly let me know what I am missing.

Thanks!

Warm Regards,
Adi

Comment: As the error message tells you: You are trying to export class `FormControl` that you have not imported. Note that it's about the import/export sections of NgModule annotation and I can't see any reason why you want to export FormControl there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My question is: why you want export FormControl?
You don't need import/export FormControl, you just need to import ReactiveFormsModule and you will be able to use FormControl.

Comment: Thank you! I removed the FormControl and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Your missing import `FromControl` from `'@material-ui/core'`

```
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
// or
import { FormControl } from '@material-ui/core';
```

Refer : https://material-ui.com/api/form-control/

Comment: Thank you for the response. We weren't using FormControl, but had copied it accidentally. Removing it fixed the issue

Comment: Oh sure, great to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new Angular 9 Project and try to serve a prod build. The issue reoccurred.

In the end, instead of making changes to angular, I decided to just go with Angular 10 as a workaround. Fortunately, everything went smoothly in the new version.